# How to use this 2 coil motor as a hand crank?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, coil

I found this used motor coil and got a few questions on how I can make it useable as a hand crank.

There are 2 coils with respectively 2 wires each. How exactly do I know the way of how each coil should be powered? I know that +/- are interchangeable for coils but how do I wire it so that I can get the generated electricity from it?

I also know that I am still missing the part that goes inside these coils (the magnet). This shouldn't be hard to research but maybe you could tell me how I can identify if this motor is brushless or not?

Maybe I am completely missing something here, so please let me know if I have to clarify things.

I tested each coil with a multimeter, they are "working" properly.

Thank you all in advance, would be nice to get a deeper understanding of things :)

[image: motor coil]

Comment: That's not even half a motor. It's easier to find a complete motor than trying to find suitable parts for that one. Scrap that one and go look for a complete motor/generator.

Comment: You're missing the rotor, the end caps, bearings and shaft. If you find a suitable rotor it will most likely be in another motor so just dump this one. The simplest way for you to learn would be to find a brushed DC motor.

Comment: I know that but I want to learn something here. Let this be my problem about the other parts. What about the wiring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply connect the two windings in series. You will need a strong permanent magnet that will fit in the opening without touching the sides, but as close to the sides as possible. North and south must be directed towards the sides, not the openings at the ends. The crank must hold the magnet tightly enough to keep it from sticking to the sides. Start with the coils disconnected and use a meter to detect voltage. You will be generating AC voltage, so a DC meter will show positive and negative alternatively as the magnet turns. That might damage an analog meter if you get too much voltage. A digital meter that shows polarity might be better. A zero-center galvanometer is another possibility. You will not get enough voltage to be useful, but it should be possible to make a demonstration.

I got reasonable demo results by just putting a magnet in a pill bottle with a scrap of plywood and a piece of paper towel. A quick twist of the bottle produced about 0.3 mA peak through 1.3 k ohms. In the picture, the magnet is mostly out of the stator so it cam be seen.

[image]

Comment: I do have a multimeter with which I can test that, thank you for the warning on the DC voltage reading. I will probably convert the AC to DC after I connected everything successfully. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. That was the kind of answer I was hoping for, it's great to see that people still care about this forum instead of just telling me I should move to other parts.

Comment: Don't forget what  @Neil_UK said about determining if you have the series connection correct. I neglected to mention that. I voted to close the question until I realized that a demonstration like this has a bit more visual educational value than a lot of other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

That's the stator from a 'universal' motor. As you've already identified that the windings are 'working', you have already found which pairs of wires go together.

The simplest way to get this object to generate for you is to spin a permanent magnet between the poles. The magnet poles should be aligned N to one pole piece, S to the other pole piece, and spun so that each pole piece gets a sequence of N, S, N, S etc facing it. This will generate an AC voltage in each winding, which you can then rectify to DC if you want. Connect the coils in series so their voltages add. It will be easy to spot whether you have phased them correctly, as if you get it wrong, the voltages will oppose each other and give zero output.

Comment: Sizing it with minimum clearance will maximize the output, too much and the output will be poor...